# Batch script set command not working properly

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I am trying to read the first line from a file and I am setting it as environment variable. Below is the variable I use

```
@echo off
if EXIST "test.dat" (
    set JAVA_HOME_PATH=
    set JAVA_PATH=
    set /p JAVA_HOME_PATH=<test.dat
    echo %JAVA_HOME_PATH%
    set JAVA_PATH=%JAVA_HOME_PATH%\bin\java
    echo %JAVA_PATH%
  )
```

Assuming the test.dat contains the path to JDK and if it is c:\JDK1.6

on running it for the first time I get

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

on running again I get

```
c:\JDK1.6
\bin\java
```

and on running again I get

```
c:\JDK1.6
c:\JDK1.6\bin\java
```

I dint change the test.dat file. But why is this happening ? Only when I run for third time all the variables getting set ? Looks weird. Am I doing anything wrong in this?

Comment: Why is there a `%` in the filename on the first line?

Comment: How exactly are you running it?

Comment: @Peter Wright: that was formatting mistake. Corrected it. Thanks for figuring it out

Comment: @DarkCthulhu: I created with the file name test.bat. In command prompt I am running it as `c:\>test.bat`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Batch always replaces any %var% in any statement with its CURRENT value and THEN runs the statement. Your IF statement runs from the IF keyword to the closing-parenthesis.

On the first run, batch substitutes (nothing) for `Java_home_path` and for `java_path` so the `ECHO %java_home_path%` is interpreted as 'echo` and batch reports its ECHO status.

HOWEVER, `java_home_path` is set to `c:\JDK1.6` from `test.dat` but `JAVA_PATH` is set to `(nothing)\bin\java`

On the second run, these existing values are duly reported, `java_home_path` is set from `test.dat` and `JAVA_PATH` is set to `c:\JDK1.6\bin\java`

On the third run, you get the names you expect reported.

Cure: (1)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if EXIST "test.dat" (
    set JAVA_HOME_PATH=
    set JAVA_PATH=
    set /p JAVA_HOME_PATH=<test.dat
    echo !JAVA_HOME_PATH!
    set JAVA_PATH=%JAVA_HOME_PATH%\bin\java
    echo !JAVA_PATH!
  )
```

cure: (2)

```
@echo off
if not EXIST "test.dat" ECHO No test.dat&goto :eof
set JAVA_HOME_PATH=
set JAVA_PATH=
set /p JAVA_HOME_PATH=<test.dat
echo %JAVA_HOME_PATH%
set JAVA_PATH=%JAVA_HOME_PATH%\bin\java
echo %JAVA_PATH%
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is one of [Delayed Expansion of variables](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php).

To fix it, simply change your script to include `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, and use `!!` instead of `%%` as so:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if EXIST "test.dat" (
    set JAVA_HOME_PATH=
    set JAVA_PATH=
    set /p JAVA_HOME_PATH=<test.dat
    echo !JAVA_HOME_PATH!
    set JAVA_PATH=!JAVA_HOME_PATH!\bin\java
    echo !JAVA_PATH!
)
```