# Batch script read file and set to environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I am writing a shell script to read a file containing key=value pair and set those variables into environment variable. I tried with the below code,

```
if EXIST "test.dat" (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (test.dat) do @set %%I
    echo setting JAVA_HOME to :: %JAVA_HOME%
    echo setting JAVA to %JAVA%
)
```

Assuming the `test.dat` has `JAVA_HOME=c:\JDK1.6` and `JAVA=c:\JDK1.6\bin\java`
Running the above code is not setting these variables, even though I have `set %%I` statement in `do`.  The two echo statements are not printing anything. What am I missing here ? Why the line which is read from file is not set into environment ?

Comment: Same Delayed Expansion of variables problem as when you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479542/batch-script-set-command-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

This does work here:

```
if exist test.dat for /f "delims=" %%i in (test.dat) do set %%i
set java
```

Output:

```
JAVA=c:\JDK1.6\bin\java
JAVA_HOME=c:\JDK1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables enclosed within **%** characters are evaluated when the line of code is *parsed*, not when it is *executed*. If you want cmd to evaluate environment variables when the line of code is executed, you need to enable 'delayed variable expansion' and enclose the environment variable names within **!** rather than **%**. For example:

```
...
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
...
if EXIST "test.txt" (
  for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (%SEURAT_SERVER_DIR%\server-variables.dat) do @set %%I
  echo setting JAVA_HOME to :: !JAVA_HOME!
  echo setting JAVA to !JAVA!
)
echo JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
echo JAVA=%JAVA%
```

Bill